# What could be making my code repeat itself when ran after I type in a input?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a small game where you need to guess a random number generated on Python, but after my first input my code repeats the first part of the code.

This is the part of the code that repeats itself:

```
def level():
    lvl = int(input("Select a difficulty: \n\n1 Easy \n2 medium \n3 hard \n4 very hard \n"))
    if lvl == 1:
        a = 1
        b = 10
        return a, b
    elif lvl == 2:
        a = 1
        b = 100
        return a, b
    elif lvl == 3:
        a = 1
        b = 1000
        return a, b
    elif lvl == 4:
        a = 1
        b = 10000
        return a, b
    else:
        print("Enter a valid number.")
        level()
```

And when ran it show like this:

```
Select a difficulty: 

1 Easy 
2 medium 
3 hard 
4 very hard 
2
Select a difficulty: 

1 Easy 
2 medium 
3 hard 
4 very hard 
2
```

After the second input it all runs normally. What could be making that part of the code repeat itself?

Comment: where is the code that calls the function?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. A!so, does the indentation in your actual code match the indentation as posted? My hunch is that your actual code has an indentation error.

Comment: Even if the indentation is correct, it is a bug that it isn't *returning* anything in the `else` case.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the function `level()` inside the function itself so I suggest you use this piece of code:

```
def level():
    lvl = int(input("Select a difficulty: \n\n1 Easy \n2 medium \n3 
          hard \n4 very hard \n"))
    if lvl == 1:
        a = 1
        b = 10
        return a, b
    elif lvl == 2:
        a = 1
        b = 100
        return a, b
    elif lvl == 3:
        a = 1
        b = 1000
        return a, b
    elif lvl == 4:
        a = 1
        b = 10000
        return a, b
    else:
        print("Enter a valid number.")
        return level()
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is no replacement for a loop.

First, ask for a valid level in a while-True-loop, then return the parameters:

```
def ask_level():
    while True:
        try:
            level = int(input("Select a difficulty: \n\n1 Easy \n2 medium \n3 hard \n4 very hard \n"))
            if 1 <= level <= 4:
                break 
        except ValueError:
            pass
        print("Enter a valid number.")

    a = 1
    if level == 1:
        b = 10
    elif level == 2:
        b = 100
    elif level == 3:
        b = 1000
    elif level == 4:
        b = 10000
    return a, b
```

Comment: This doesn't explain what OP is reporting. Recursion  is  unlikely to be the problem. A loop is more idiomatic, but recursion isn't an actual bug here.

Comment: Thanks for the help! That made me realize that I could clean the code a lot.

Answer (score 0):

calling the function inside itself is causing this is your function call which is inside your function so I suggested you take it out of your function

Comment: But if the user input is a valid number then it does not matter.

Comment: For this code to execute you need to call the function outside at least once then code will execute if he enters a valid number then it will run if it is not a valid number then it will be in a loop.

Comment: To start the code give it outside else condition and outside function once starts what you have done will work

Comment: That's exactly the point. It's a loop and the only way to break out of it is to provide a valid input.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the feedback! I realized I was calling the variables from one function to another incorrectly. I'm just starting on this and was not aware how to call the variables correctly.

This is the next part of the code that I omitted (didn't knew it'd make a difference):

```
def game():
    tries = 1
    a, b = level()
    random = rd.randint(a, b)
    guessed = 0
    ...
```

And after defining the functions I  was calling them like this:

```
while True:
    level()
    game()
```

I removed level() on the last part and now it's running correctly.